# Google Play Services Library not installing

Tags: android, eclipse, google-play

I am making and Android app on Eclipse that requires the current location of the user and I came across this error:

```
   - GooglePlayServicesClient cannot be resolved to be a type
```

I then searched around for solutions and found a tutorial.

I was following [this tutorial](http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html) and once I got to step 4 (the one that requires you to copy the library project from /extras/google/google_play_services/libproject/google-play-services_lib/ and move it to my Android project), I saw that in my extras folder, nothing was in the extras/google folder even though I just successfully installed the latest Google Play services package from my Android SDK Manager.

I have tried uninstalling and installing the Google Play services package again, but that doesn't work. I restarted the Android SDK Manager, Eclipse and my computer. I also saw that other packages are installing correctly.

Comment: make sure that you are using the sdk path properly? Check if you have another copy of sdk

Comment: Are you using emulator?

Comment: @ViswanathL I just fixed it. Incorrect SDK path. Thanks - I forgot I installed it a couple years ago.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure **SDK path** is correct.